# CodeMirror foldCode method not working

Tags: javascript, html, web, ide, codemirror

I am trying to write an online editor and at the moment am trying to implement code folding. On the CodeMirror website they do a demo that uses the foldCode command that comes from the foldcode.js addon. 
Here is my code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Code Mirror Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="codemirror-5.4/lib/codemirror.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="codemirror-5.4/lib/codemirror.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="codemirror-5.4/theme/neat.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="codemirror-5.4/mode/javascript/javascript.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/Main.css">
    <script type="type/javascript" src="codemirror-5.4/addon/fold/foldcode.js"></script>
    <script type="type/javascript" src="codemirror-5.4/addon/fold/foldgutter.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="codemirror-5.4/addon/fold/foldgutter.css">

</head>
<body>
    <script>
        window.onload = function() {
            var editor = CodeMirror(document.body, {
                mode: "javascript",
                lineNumbers: true,
                theme: "neat",
                extraKeys: {"Ctrl-Q": function(cm) { cm.foldCode(cm.getCursor()); }},
                foldgutter: true,
                gutters: ["CodeMirror-linenumbers", "CodeMirror-foldgutter"]
            });
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

IntelliJ is telling me that foldCode is an unresolved method. Im wondering if maybe I am importing the script wrong or may be foldCode was depreciated with the newest versions of CodeMirror?

Answer (score 5):

You don't seem to be loading any actual folding functions. For JavaScript, you probably want `addon/fold/brace-fold.js`.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the other answers, add

```
editor.foldCode(CodeMirror.Pos(0, 0));
```

outside of your `var editor`

Answer (score 0):

change

```
foldgutter: true;
```

to

```
foldGutter: true;
```